# Unknown code added to Google colab notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, data-analysis

Unknown code was added to my code in google colab notebook
The code i had written:

```
    url = "api_url"

    response = requests.get(url)
    res = response.json()

    bin = pd.DataFrame(res)
    bin['time'] = bin['time'].apply(lambda x: t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", t.localtime(int(str(x)[:-3]))))

    bin.head(5)
```

But somehow an additional import was added to my code -

```
    from ctypes import BigEndianStructure
    url = "api_url"

    response = requests.get(url)
    res = response.json()

    bin = pd.DataFrame(res)
    bin['time'] = bin['time'].apply(lambda x: t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", t.localtime(int(str(x)[:-3]))))

    bin.head(5)
```

How did this ***from ctypes import BigEndianStructure*** import get here?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Seems kind of strange to me that it was added without you typing it down. Anyways, check your variable naming: don't overwrite "bin" variable as it is already a built-in function.

Comment: yeah it is strange, i am certain i did not add that import there and you think it could be happening because of overwriting bin? 
Thanks..